# How to reduce the number of samples in audio data array using python

Tags: python, numpy, audio, matplotlib, pydub

I am plotting an audio samples amplitude at every frame present in that sample something like this:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("test.mp3")
print(len(sound))
print(len(sound.raw_data))
data = np.fromstring(sound.raw_data, dtype=np.int16)
left, right = data[0::2], data[1::2]
plt.plot(left)
```

In the process I noticed that the length of sound AudioSegment is different from sound raw_data why is that the case?

and also as the test.mp3 duration gets lengthier the ticks on x axis goes into some million so my doubt was how can we plot the data at some lower sample rate or in other words how can I reduce the number of samples in *data* array?

Here is my first thought: calculate the average of first 10 or 20 sample in an audio data array and represent them as a one point so that way we can reduce the number of samples. However this might cause some information loss and performance issues.

does python have any alternate way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pydub, `len(sound)` is the duration in milliseconds, where `len(sound.raw_data)` would be the number of bytes of total audio data.

If you are working with CD-quality sound (44.1kHz, 16 bit, stereo) you would expect each millisecond to be roughly 44 samples (44100 / 1000), and two bytes (16 bits) per sample, doubled again for left/right channels. So roughly 176 bytes per millisecond.

To create a plot like you see in many audio editors, the most common approach is to get the rms of the audio in chunks.

if you want a plot that is 400px wide, you'd do something like…

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("...")

num_chunks = 400 #px
chunk_size = int(len(sound) / num_chunks #ms))

loudness_over_time = []
for i in range(0, len(sound), chunk_size):
    chunk = sound[i:i+chunk_size]
    loudness_over_time.append(chunk.rms)
```

note, I haven't tested this code